# Display property value of each section in table like in clocktable

Tags: org-mode, org-table

**Context** As far as I know it is possible to define [properties](http://orgmode.org/manual/Property-syntax.html#Property-syntax) for a section in a `PROPERTIES` drawer like this:

```
* Introduction
:PROPERTIES:
:PlannedPages: 0.5
:ActualPages: 0.5
:END:
```

You can see that there are two properties, that should reflect the number of pages that I plan to write for this section and the number of pages that I actually wrote.

**Question**
Do you know an example that shows to some extent how to program a [dynamic block](http://orgmode.org/manual/Dynamic-blocks.html) similiar to [`CLOCKTABLE`](http://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html#The-clock-table) which maintains a table that contains sections in it's rows and the values of some properties in it's columns?

```
:DOCUMENTSCOPE: 
|                   | Planned | Actual |
| Section           |   Pages | Pages  |
|-------------------+---------+--------|
| Introduction      |     0.5 |        |
| Background        |       2 |        |
| Thesis objectives |       1 |        |
| Time schedule     |     0.5 |        |
:END:
```

Comment: I found [org-collector](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-collector.html) but it gives an 'Before first headline' error, also it's currently not supporting indentation according to the headline level and is printing escape characters in headlines :/

Answer (score 5):

The [columnview](http://orgmode.org/manual/Capturing-column-view.html) dynamic block does this:

```
 #+BEGIN: columnview :hlines 1 :id global
 | ITEM            | PlannedPages | ActualPages |
 |-----------------+--------------+-------------|
 | * first section |            7 |           3 |
 |-----------------+--------------+-------------|
 | * Introduction  |          0.5 |         0.5 |
 #+END:
```

`C-c C-c` on the `#+BEGIN:` line will update the block.  The option `:id global` makes is collect the whole file, `:id local` would collect only that entry.

---

Minimal example:

```
#+TITLE: Page planning example
#+COLUMNS: %25ITEM %4PlannedPages(Planned pages){+} %4ActualPages(Actual pages){+}
#+PROPERTY: ActualPages_All "" 0.25 0.5 1 1.5 2
#+PROPERTY: PlannedPages_ALL "" 0.25 0.5 1 1.5 2

#+BEGIN: columnview :hlines 0 :id global :maxlevel 1
| ITEM           | Planned pages | Actual pages |
|----------------+---------------+--------------|
| * Introduction |           1.5 |              |
| * Main part    |           3.5 |              |
| * Conclusions  |           0.5 |              |
#+END

* Introduction
  :PROPERTIES:
  :PlannedPages: 1.5
  :END:
* Main part
  :PROPERTIES:
  :PlannedPages: 3.5
  :END:
** Section 1
   :PROPERTIES:
   :PlannedPages: 2
   :END:
** Section 2
   :PROPERTIES:
   :PlannedPages: 1.5
   :END:
* Conclusions
  :PROPERTIES:
  :PlannedPages: 0.5
  :END:
```

Comment: Hello Erik, thank you for your answer. I looked again into it and found the editing features very nice. I did not know them before and did not see an advantage of the column view. I have added a minmal example.

Comment: The only issue with this minimal example is that the allowed values for `ActualPages` are not recognized. Do you see a reason for this?

Comment: For single level tables this solution is fine. Is there a possibility to adapt the column view similiar to the clock table such that it indent's children and strips tags and todo's from the `Item` column?

Comment: I don't see any obvious way to indent the table by level or modify how things are displayed beyond what `COLUMNS` does normally.

Comment: In org-mode release 9.0 there is a new parameter `:indent` introduced: https://orgmode.org/Changes_old.html Unfortunately in contrast to clock tables there is no function similar to `org-clocktable-indent-string` that could be overriden but a hard-coded constant in `org-dblock-write:columnview` instead.